# Android How to Get 'last_page' object of Given JSONObject

Tags: android, json

```
[{"0":"2","sub_cat_id":"2","1":"1","cat_id":"1","2":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_title":"Art - Collectibles","3":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_des":"Art - Collectibles","4":"1","sub_cat_status":"1","5":"1","temp_id":"1","6":"Type","type\/make":"Type","7":"normal","is_important":"normal","8":"29213","post_id":"29213","9":"Flower holder vase","post_title":"Flower holder vase","10":"Hand painted Chinese vase with silk flowers","post_des":"Hand painted Chinese vase with silk flowers","11":"2013-03-15 10:03:07","post_date":"2013-03-15 10:03:07","12":"2013-03-15 10:03:07","edit_date":"2013-03-15 10:03:07","13":"1","post_status":"1","14":"5","user_id":"5","15":"0","featuered":"0","16":"2","17":"1","18":"1000","post_price":"1000","19":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29213\/1363325588-flower-holder-vase-lmf-com-pk.jpg","post_img":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29213\/1363325588-flower-holder-vase-lmf-com-pk.jpg","20":"1","post_country_id":"1","21":"4","post_state_id":"4","22":"23","post_city_id":"23","23":"olx","post_ref":"olx"},{"0":"2","sub_cat_id":"2","1":"1","cat_id":"1","2":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_title":"Art - Collectibles","3":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_des":"Art - Collectibles","4":"1","sub_cat_status":"1","5":"1","temp_id":"1","6":"Type","type\/make":"Type","7":"normal","is_important":"normal","8":"29243","post_id":"29243","9":"fast stitching","post_title":"fast stitching","10":"we can provide all kind of stitching at lowest possible price and on time. We are also available for stitching botique dresses.","post_des":"we can provide all kind of stitching at lowest possible price and on time. We are also available for stitching botique dresses.","11":"2013-03-15 10:03:27","post_date":"2013-03-15 10:03:27","12":"2013-03-15 10:03:27","edit_date":"2013-03-15 10:03:27","13":"1","post_status":"1","14":"5","user_id":"5","15":"0","featuered":"0","16":"2","17":"1","18":"","post_price":"","19":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29243\/1363325668-fast-stitching-lmf-com-pk.jpg","post_img":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29243\/1363325668-fast-stitching-lmf-com-pk.jpg","20":"1","post_country_id":"1","21":"4","post_state_id":"4","22":"23","post_city_id":"23","23":"olx","post_ref":"olx"},{"0":"2","sub_cat_id":"2","1":"1","cat_id":"1","2":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_title":"Art - Collectibles","3":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_des":"Art - Collectibles","4":"1","sub_cat_status":"1","5":"1","temp_id":"1","6":"Type","type\/make":"Type","7":"normal","is_important":"normal","8":"29249","post_id":"29249","9":"water colour painting","post_title":"water colour painting","10":"water colour and more available.","post_des":"water colour and more available.","11":"2013-03-15 10:03:43","post_date":"2013-03-15 10:03:43","12":"2013-03-15 10:03:43","edit_date":"2013-03-15 10:03:43","13":"1","post_status":"1","14":"5","user_id":"5","15":"0","featuered":"0","16":"2","17":"1","18":"3200","post_price":"3200","19":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29249\/1363325685-water-colour-painting-lmf-com-pk.jpg","post_img":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29249\/1363325685-water-colour-painting-lmf-com-pk.jpg","20":"1","post_country_id":"1","21":"5","post_state_id":"5","22":"44","post_city_id":"44","23":"olx","post_ref":"olx"},{"0":"2","sub_cat_id":"2","1":"1","cat_id":"1","2":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_title":"Art - Collectibles","3":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_des":"Art - Collectibles","4":"1","sub_cat_status":"1","5":"1","temp_id":"1","6":"Type","type\/make":"Type","7":"normal","is_important":"normal","8":"29298","post_id":"29298","9":"House","post_title":"House","10":"Very beautiful","post_des":"Very beautiful","11":"2013-03-15 10:03:49","post_date":"2013-03-15 10:03:49","12":"2013-03-15 10:03:49","edit_date":"2013-03-15 10:03:49","13":"1","post_status":"1","14":"5","user_id":"5","15":"0","featuered":"0","16":"2","17":"1","18":"25000","post_price":"25000","19":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29298\/1363325810-house-lmf-com-pk.jpg","post_img":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29298\/1363325810-house-lmf-com-pk.jpg","20":"1","post_country_id":"1","21":"7","post_state_id":"7","22":"83","post_city_id":"83","23":"olx","post_ref":"olx"},{"0":"2","sub_cat_id":"2","1":"1","cat_id":"1","2":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_title":"Art - Collectibles","3":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_des":"Art - Collectibles","4":"1","sub_cat_status":"1","5":"1","temp_id":"1","6":"Type","type\/make":"Type","7":"normal","is_important":"normal","8":"29374","post_id":"29374","9":"Rana Atiq Amaizing Art Gallery Work","post_title":"Rana Atiq Amaizing Art Gallery Work","10":"Handmade Art,Paintings & Antique Items.......Art Calligrapher All Kind Of Paintings.Handmade Frames.Advertiser Advertising.Home Decoration Service Avalible.Please Visit.............Shop # 20, Lane # 8,Deffence Bazar DHA ,Karachi&Toheed Commercial Street NO # 33Near Abdullah Photo State.Mobile : 03412030283 ,03002315193","post_des":"Handmade Art,Paintings & Antique Items.......Art Calligrapher All Kind Of Paintings.Handmade Frames.Advertiser Advertising.Home Decoration Service Avalible.Please Visit.............Shop # 20, Lane # 8,Deffence Bazar DHA ,Karachi&Toheed Commercial Street NO # 33Near Abdullah Photo State.Mobile : 03412030283 ,03002315193","11":"2013-03-15 10:03:39","post_date":"2013-03-15 10:03:39","12":"2013-03-15 10:03:39","edit_date":"2013-03-15 10:03:39","13":"1","post_status":"1","14":"5","user_id":"5","15":"0","featuered":"0","16":"2","17":"1","18":"","post_price":"","19":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29374\/1363325988-rana-atiq-amaizing-art-gallery-work-lmf-com-pk.jpg","post_img":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29374\/1363325988-rana-atiq-amaizing-art-gallery-work-lmf-com-pk.jpg","20":"1","post_country_id":"1","21":"8","post_state_id":"8","22":"107","post_city_id":"107","23":"olx","post_ref":"olx"},{"0":"2","sub_cat_id":"2","1":"1","cat_id":"1","2":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_title":"Art - Collectibles","3":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_des":"Art - Collectibles","4":"1","sub_cat_status":"1","5":"1","temp_id":"1","6":"Type","type\/make":"Type","7":"normal","is_important":"normal","8":"29430","post_id":"29430","9":"Original paintings 2013......","post_title":"Original paintings 2013......","10":"ORIGINAL PAINTINGS HANDMADEacrylic on canvas1&2\u00a0 30x243&4\u00a0 24x24price: 30000\/= to 45000\/=cell: 03082905258","post_des":"ORIGINAL PAINTINGS HANDMADEacrylic on canvas1&2\u00a0 30x243&4\u00a0 24x24price: 30000\/= to 45000\/=cell: 03082905258","11":"2013-03-15 14:03:25","post_date":"2013-03-15 14:03:25","12":"2013-03-15 14:03:25","edit_date":"2013-03-15 14:03:25","13":"1","post_status":"1","14":"5","user_id":"5","15":"0","featuered":"0","16":"2","17":"1","18":"","post_price":"","19":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29430\/1363340006-original-paintings-2013-lmf-com-pk.jpg","post_img":".\/uploads\/lmf-classifieds-pk\/folder1\/2013-03-15\/29430\/1363340006-original-paintings-2013-lmf-com-pk.jpg","20":"1","post_country_id":"1","21":"8","post_state_id":"8","22":"107","post_city_id":"107","23":"olx","post_ref":"olx"},{"0":"2","sub_cat_id":"2","1":"1","cat_id":"1","2":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_title":"Art - Collectibles","3":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_des":"Art - Collectibles","4":"1","sub_cat_status":"1","5":"1","temp_id":"1","6":"Type","type\/make":"Type","7":"normal","is_important":"normal","8":"29620","post_id":"29620","9":"studio166 oil paintings","post_title":"studio166 oil paintings","10":"artist in oil paintings figure lanscaping forests birds peacock peagens lions animals parrats. poet writen saairah happy birthday critical.","post_des":"artist in oil paintings figure lanscaping forests birds peacock peagens lions animals parrats. poet writen saairah happy birthday critical.","11":"2013-03-15 14:03:35","post_date":"2013-03-15 14:03:35","12":"2013-03-15 14:03:35","edit_date":"2013-03-15 14:03:35","13":"1","post_status":"1","14":"5","user_id":"5","15":"0","featuered":"0","16":"2","17":"1","18":"","post_price":"","19":"uploads\/no_image.jpg","post_img":"uploads\/no_image.jpg","20":"1","post_country_id":"1","21":"7","post_state_id":"7","22":"83","post_city_id":"83","23":"olx","post_ref":"olx"},{"0":"2","sub_cat_id":"2","1":"1","cat_id":"1","2":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_title":"Art - Collectibles","3":"Art - Collectibles","sub_cat_des":"Art - Collectibles","4":"1","sub_cat_status":"1","5":"1","temp_id":"1","6":"Type","type\/make":"Type","7":"normal","is_important":"normal","8":"29722","post_id":"29722","9":"Services","post_title":"Services","10":"OUR BRIEF INTRODUCTIONDear Sir,We are pleased to introduce ourselves as a Leading Importers,\u00a0Exporters.& Genereal Order Suppliers for Used Earth Moving Equipments\u00a0(Buldozers, Wheel Loaders), Used Construction Machinery (Excavator),\u00a0Used Road Construction Machinery (Motor Graders, Road Rollers,\u00a0Asphalt Finishers), Lifting Equipments ( Cranes & Fork Lifters)Brands We Deal:-Komatsu, Caterpillar, Toyota, TCM, Kato, Tadano, P&H, Kobelco, Hitachi, Daewoo, Solar, Samsung, Volvo, Groove, Furukawa, Mitsubishi, Dynapac, Sakai, Ingersoll Rand, Hyster, Nissan, Nigata, JCB, Halla, Helli,\u00a0Product we Deals :-FORK LIFTERS, CRANES, BULDOZERS, MOTOR GRADERS, WHEEL LOADERS, ASPHALT FINISHERS, EXCAVATORS, WHEEL EXCAVATORS, ROAD ROLLERS.
\nWe are regularly importing All the above mentioned units alongwith Fork Lifters & Cranes.
\nIf you have some inquiry for Purchase or you have some units for Sale, please feel free to contact us.
\nShall be looking forward to have your quick & positive Response.Thanks & Best RegardsA.H. Shaikh0320-5013123
\nA.R. Puri0333-4350628
\nMubashar Mehmood0333-4547077
\nA. A Construction & MachineryDEALS IN USED & NEW CONSTRUCTION MACHINERY, EARTH MOVING EQUIPMENTS,\u00a0LIFTING EQUIPMENTS, FORK LIFTERS, TRUCKS, CRANES, NEW & USED SPARE\u00a0PARTS.","post_des":"OUR BRIEF INTRODUCTIONDear Sir,We are pleased to introduce ourselves as a Leading Importers,\u00a0Exporters.& Genereal Order Suppliers for Used Earth Moving Equipments\u00a0(Buldozers, Wheel Loaders), Used Construction Machinery (Excavator),\u00a0Used Road Construction Machinery (Motor Graders, Road Rollers,\u00a0Asphalt Finishers), Lifting Equipments ( Cranes & Fork Lifters)Brands We Deal:-Komatsu, Caterpillar, Toyota, TCM, Kato, Tadano, P&H, Kobelco, Hitachi, Daewoo, Solar, Samsung, Volvo, Groove, Furukawa, Mitsubishi, Dynapac, Sakai, Ingersoll Rand, Hyster, Nissan, Nigata, JCB, Halla, Helli,\u00a0Product we Deals :-FORK LIFTERS, CRANES, BULDOZERS, MOTOR GRADERS, WHEEL LOADERS, ASPHALT FINISHERS, EXCAVATORS, WHEEL EXCAVATORS, ROAD ROLLERS.
\nWe are regularly importing All the above mentioned units alongwith Fork Lifters & Cranes.
\nIf you have some inquiry for Purchase or you have some units for Sale, please feel free to contact us.
\nShall be looking forward to have your quick & positive Response.Thanks & Best RegardsA.H. Shaikh0320-5013123
\nA.R. Puri0333-4350628
\nMubashar Mehmood0333-4547077
\nA. A Construction & MachineryDEALS IN USED & NEW CONSTRUCTION MACHINERY, EARTH MOVING EQUIPMENTS,\u00a0LIFTING EQUIPMENTS, FORK LIFTERS, TRUCKS, CRANES, NEW & USED SPARE\u00a0PARTS.","11":"2013-03-15 17:03:02","post_date":"2013-03-15 17:03:02","12":"2013-03-15 17:03:02","edit_date":"2013-03-15 17:03:02","13":"1","post_status":"1","14":"5","user_id":"5","15":"0","featuered":"0","16":"2","17":"1","18":"Free","post_price":"Free","19":"uploads\/no_image.jpg","post_img":"uploads\/no_image.jpg","20":"1","post_country_id":"1","21":"7","post_state_id":"7","22":"83","post_city_id":"83","23":"olx","post_ref":"olx"}]{"last_page":8}
```

Comment: Really? Why would you do this?

Comment: Your JSON string isn't valid.  You have a JSONArray and a JSONObject that run up against each other but aren't contained in a common JSONObject.  To see the exact problem you can format your object using an [online formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and see exactly where your problem is.

Comment: Basically i want "last_page" string from this object {"last_page":8}

Comment: What kind of question is this? Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the many existing JSON libraries, parse the string and use the API provided by the library? See http://json.org/, there's a list of libraries you could use.